# Hint: Hölder Inequality with $\theta$ application

Tags: real-analysis, integration, holder-inequality

Let $\frac{1}{r}=\frac{\theta}{p}+\frac{1-\theta}{q}$ where $1\leq p<r<q\leq \infty$
and $\theta \in ]0,1[$, as well as $f \in L^{p} \cap L^{q}$. Show that $||f||_{r}\leq||f||_{p}^{\theta}\times||f||_{q}^{1-\theta}$

I get to the point:

$||f||_{r}=...=((\int_{\mathbb R}|f|^{r}d\mu)^{\frac{1}{p}})^{\theta}\times((\int_{\mathbb R}|f|^{r}d\mu)^{\frac{1}{q}})^{1-\theta}$

but this leads to a dead end. Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have by the Holder ineq that
$$\Vert f\Vert_r=\Big\Vert \vert f\vert ^{\theta}\vert f\vert ^{1-\theta}\Big\Vert_r\leq \Big\Vert \vert f\vert ^\theta\Big\Vert_{p/\theta} \Big\Vert \vert f\vert ^{1-\theta}\Big\Vert_{q/(1-\theta)}.$$